# How to convert my website to app using React Native Expo WebBrowser?

Tags: react-native, expo

I want to make an app that shows the URL I passes. I tried react native web view and it got some issues while deep linking and others. I found expo webbrowser and I find that solves my problem.
The code I tried is the following

```
import React, { useState } from 'react';
import { Button, Text, View, StyleSheet } from 'react-native';
import * as WebBrowser from 'expo-web-browser';
import Constants from 'expo-constants';

export default function App() {
  const [result, setResult] = useState(null);

  const _handlePressButtonAsync = async () => {
    let result = await WebBrowser.openBrowserAsync('https://expo.io');
    setResult(result);
  };
  return (
    <View style={styles.container}>
      <Button title="Open WebBrowser" onPress={_handlePressButtonAsync} />
      <Text>{result && JSON.stringify(result)}</Text>
    </View>
  );
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    flex: 1,
    alignItems: 'center',
    justifyContent: 'center',
    paddingTop: Constants.statusBarHeight,
    backgroundColor: '#ecf0f1',
  },
});
```

It's the demo code from the expo webbrowser site. I want to remove the address bar on the top and launch the website without clicking the button. The following code didn't work

```
let result = await WebBrowser.openBrowserAsync('https://expo.io',{showTitle:false});
```

....

```
return (_handlePressButtonAsync);
```

[Expo Webbrowser](https://docs.expo.io/versions/latest/sdk/webbrowser/#webbrowseropenbrowserasyncurl)